# Ajax can not get data from Django view

Tags: django, ajax

I have a request to use Ajax to get data from Django views. This project was generated through cookiecutter
Here is my code:

`config/urls.py`:

```
# API URLS
urlpatterns += [
    # API base url
    path("api/", include("config.api_router")),]
```

`./config/api_router.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter, SimpleRouter

from project.users.api.views import UserViewSet
from app import views

if settings.DEBUG:
    router = DefaultRouter()
else:
    router = SimpleRouter()

router.register("users", UserViewSet)


app_name = "api"
urlpatterns = router.urls
urlpatterns += [
    path("chart-data", views.chart_data),
]
```

`app/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
def chart_data(request):
return render(request, 'pages/home.html')

def click(request):
    data_for_ajax = {
        'a': {1: 1, 2: 2}, 'b': {3: 3}, 'c': {4: 4, 5: 5}
    }
    return JsonResponse(data_for_ajax)
```

`project/templates/pages/home.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      function click() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "api/chart-data",
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
      })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="click()">Click me</button>
</body>
```

When I accessed http://localhost:8000/api/chart-data and clicked the "Click me button", there is nothing in the console, and there is no error.

Comment: in your `api/chart-data` you are just rendering new template and your `click` view function is not called anywhere

Comment: I removed the `click` function and use this to instead, and there is still nothing in console.
```
def chart_data(request):
    data_for_ajax = {
        'a': {1: 1, 2: 2}, 'b': {3: 3}, 'c': {4: 4, 5: 5}
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', data_for_ajax)
```